# simplecov report 0.0% covered

Tags: ruby, rspec, simplecov

I'm working on a small plugin and included simplecov.
In my gem file I have the line:

```
gem 'simplecov', :require => false, :group => :test
```

In my test file I put the line `require "projectname/devuntil/rspec/spec_helper"`
at the very top of the file. 
In my spec_helper.rb file I add simplecov at the top of the file

```
if ENV['COVERAGE']
  require 'simplecov'
  require 'coveralls'

  puts "require simplecov and coveralls"
  SimpleCov.formatter = SimpleCov::Formatter::MultiFormatter[
    SimpleCov::Formatter::HTMLFormatter,
    Coveralls::SimpleCov::Formatter
  ]

  SimpleCov.start do
    add_filter 'spec/'
    add_filter 'vendor/'
    puts "Start simple coverage"
  end
end
```

When I try to run test with command `COVERAGE=true bundle exec rspec` it shows:

```
[root@node1 logstash-input-imap]# COVERAGE=true bundle exec rspec
Coverage may be inaccurate; set the "--debug" command line option, or do JRUBY_OPTS="--debug" or set the "debug.fullTrace=true" option in your .jrubyrc
require simplecov and coveralls
/usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/gems/logstash-devutils-1.3.3-java/lib/logstash/devutils/rspec/spec_helper.rb:6:in `<main>': [DEPRECATION] ::[] is deprecated. Use ::new instead.
Start simple coverage
/usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.7.0/gems/simplecov-0.15.0/lib/simplecov.rb:48: warning: tracing (e.g. set_trace_func) will not capture all events without --debug flag
--- jar coordinate com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind already loaded with version 2.7.4 - omit version 2.7.3
--- jar coordinate com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations already loaded with version 2.7.0 - omit version 2.7.3
--- jar coordinate com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-afterburner already loaded with version 2.7.4 - omit version 2.7.3
--- jar coordinate com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core already loaded with version 2.7.4 - omit version 2.7.3
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
Sending Logstash's logs to  which is now configured via log4j2.properties
Run options: exclude {:redis=>true, :socket=>true, :performance=>true, :couchdb=>true, :elasticsearch=>true, :elasticsearch_secure=>true, :export_cypher=>true, :integration=>true, :windows=>true}

Randomized with seed 6877
.function called
.function called
.function called
.function called
.function called
.function called
.

Finished in 4.04 seconds (files took 16.56 seconds to load)
7 examples, 0 failures

Randomized with seed 6877

Coverage report generated for RSpec to /root/Downloads/logstash-input-imap/coverage. 0 / 88 LOC (0.0%) covered.
[Coveralls] Outside the Travis environment, not sending data.
```

Although my function called but it still showed 0.0% covered.
What might be the problem here and how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: Can you share the full `spec_helper` and the spec file you are running?

Comment: This is my spec_helper file. it is an open source. https://github.com/elastic/logstash-devutils/blob/master/lib/logstash/devutils/rspec/spec_helper.rb

Comment: And this is my spec file https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-imap/blob/master/spec/inputs/imap_spec.rb

Comment: Why can't we see the results of `puts "Start simple coverage"` in the output you've pasted? It's not there or you edited it out?

Comment: I downloaded this source code and add some debug. It is just some simple line to show to result to console `(puts "some things")`. In the link that I sent to you it is the open source and simply understand equally as my source code.

Comment: I edited my question (change log put out in console). Could you please check it for me?

Comment: as I see simplecov is reporting some issues: `Coverage may be inaccurate; set the "--debug" command line option,` - can you investigate this path? Let's see what it has to say :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to create .jrubyrc in your project root with these contents:

cli.debug=true

debug.fullTrace=true